# What is the right way to add a variable where-clause to this update function

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I'm made a database class in php. Now i was testing the update function in it. It returns an syntax error or an unknown column error depending on how the where-clause is formed.

I tried:

```
'woord = \'uiteindelijk\'' and 'woord = \"uiteindelijk\"' and 
'woord = "uiteindelijk"' and more
```

I also tried different quotes and backsticks in de functions query but it al gave me the same errors.

My question is what is the right way to form the where-clause is this example if it possible ofcourse. And if not how can i fix it.

part of database.mysqli.php

```
<?php

class myDB {

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once('config.php');

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);  
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
    }

    public function close() {
        $this->mysqli->close(); 
    }

    private function check($input) {
        if(is_string($input)) {
            $input = trim($input);
            return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($input);   
        }       
        elseif(is_int($input)) {
            return $input;
        }
        elseif($input === true || $input === false) {
            return $input;
        }
        else {
            die('invalid input');
        }   
    }
    public function update($table, $data, $where) {
        $table = $this->check($table);
        $where = $this->check($where);
        $result = '';
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $update = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                $key = $this->check($key);
                $val = $this->check($val);  
                $update[] .= $key . '=\'' . $val . '\'';
            }
            $query = 'UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . implode(',', $update) . ' WHERE ' . $where;
            if($this->mysqli->query($query)) {
                $result = 'Last updated row id is: '.$this->mysqli->insert_id;
            } 
            else {
                $result = $this->mysqli->error;
            }
        }   
        return $result;
    }
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
require_once('database.mysqli.php');
$db = new myDB;
$data = array('woord' => 'gewoontjes', 'lengte' => 10);
$result = $db->update('galgje', $data, 'woord = \'uiteindelijk\'');
echo $result;
$db->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are missing a closing ' on the woord in your update call

Comment: Also if you want to be a little more solid so you dont have to concat a where clause through your logic you should adopt an array version of Where KEY=VALUE but then you also have to deal with the logic gates between those elements. e.g. Where a=a AND b=b OR c!=f

Comment: What about `("galgje", $data, "woord = 'uiteindelijk'")`

Comment: @Scottzozer adding a closing quote on woord doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried that but it gives an the syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"uiteindelijk\"' at line 1

Comment: Probably because of the (single) quotes in `$query = 'UPDATE '....` and in `$update[] .= $key . '=\'' . $val . '\'';` and should try to use double quotes instead. I never use single quotes to wrap with, especially when it comes to querying.

Comment: Fred-ii is right! try that out it should solve things

Comment: @Scottzozer As i explained in my answer, if you escape quotes which are part of the syntax of the statement (see line 2 of the update method escaping the whole where clause), then you will have escaped quotes directly in your statement, which is not valid sql. No way to workaround this.

Comment: Correct, and Fred-ii says that in his post above me... Shows what is going on and how you should use double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from escape_string in your check method. This function is used to escape precise parts inside a statement, you cannot apply it to the where clause as a whole in such a generic way.

If you ever know for sure that your inputs are safe (not containing special characters breaking the sql statement, malicious or not), then simply remove the escaping.

Or if you think that they may contain special characters, for good reasons or to possibly drag a sql injection, then you have to provide a more constrained interface so that you can build the where clause yourself with the appropriate escaping. For example :

```
public function update($table, $data, $woord) {
    ...
    $where = 'woord = \'' . $this->check($woord) . '\'';
    ...
}
```

**Edit**: I know it may sound too much constrained but security comes at a price. For something more flexible, you could have a look at prepared statements. They let you use placeholders, for example `WHERE woord = ? AND id < ?`, which you can bind to variables with something like :

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $woord, $id); // 'si' -> 1:string, 2:integer
```

In this case, mysqli applies escaping internaly on bound strings, so you don't have to worry about it.

Note that you cannot use a placeholder to replace the whole where clause. `WHERE ?` with `$stmt->bind_param('s', $where);` will *not* work.

Last thing, PDO, an alternative API to access your database in PHP, supports named placeholders (`WHERE woord = :woord` instead of `WHERE woord = ?`).

Comment: Thanks. I thought i already tried it without the check function but my where clause was probably wrong at that time. i fixed it like this: $where = '\''.$this->check($where).'\''; and now can use the function like this: update('galgje', $data, 'woord="uiteindelijk"'). The problem now is that the function always returns last updated row id is: 0 even if the word is already updated and not is the database anymore.

Comment: The fix you tried will not work, it gives a valid syntax but wrong results because now your $where variable is evaluated as a raw string cast to boolean, giving FALSE in your example. You would have the same result with `update('galgje', $data, 'i am a teapot');` (the evaluation is based on the 1st character of the string).

Comment: Yes it is nt the right way i see. altough the words will change if i use it this way. I already did take a look at mysqli prepare but couldn't think about an function for it becuase you don't know how many and what type of params you need to bind.